# Setting a switch to act as a clock for Nexys4-ddr FPGA board

Tags: clock, fpga, vivado

I'm using Xilinx's new software Vivado and Digilent's new board the Nexys4-ddr. I'm trying to have a hardware switch act as a clock to allow me to manual progress through a timed scenario. The information I am given is:

```
set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets { clk }];
```

> Add the above code to the XDC file and set the clock as SW15.

I've added this in however I am unsure whether I should be "setting the clock to SW15" in the given code line. For instance:

```
set_property CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE FALSE [get_nets { SW15 }]
```

Or if I don't, then how do I alter the SW15 'set property' code to pass that hardware reference to the new clock line?

This is what the SW15 code currently looks like:

```
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { clk }]; #IO_L21P_T3_DQS_14 Sch=sw[15]
```

Comment: You *can not* use a hardware switch as a clock signal. But you can use it as a clock enable signal. If you would like to stick to your plan, you need to implement diverse filters and preprocessing circuits to transform a switch into a clock signal.

Comment: You should be able too. The direction to do this came from digilent's own teaching documents. I've seen examples of people doing this within the old constrains file used for ISE projects. Unfortunately the examples don't translate.

Comment: A clock signal is a glitch-free, periodic signal with a fixed frequency and duty cycle. Otherwise it's just a signal. So inputting highs and lows via a slide switch will not be a clock!

Comment: No I know it won't be by definition be a clock, however Xilinx have this alteration available that allows a switch to be used as a clock for whatever reason. I can just use `rising_edge(SW15)` for the same purpose but it was just if anyone knew how to implement the xdc alteration.